# Will Bioviosionary and Mirrorweave always end in a draw if every player has 4 or more creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have the following scenario:

**Player A**: Has 4 creatures on the board, one of them is *[Biovisionary](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Biovisionary)*.

> At the beginning of the end step, if you control four or more creatures named Biovisionary, you win the game.

**Player B**: Also has 4 creatures on the board.

**Player A** draws *[Mirrorweave](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mirrorweave)* and plays it on his turn.

> Each other creature becomes a copy of target non-legendary creature until end of turn.

So first I fought **Player A** should win because it is his end step, but referring to this question here [At the beginning of the end step" meaning and comparison to "your end step" and "each end step](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/50205/at-the-beginning-of-the-end-step-meaning-and-comparison-to-your-end-step-and), the end step means any players end step.

Therefore, both **Player A** and **B** have 4 *“Bioviosionary”* that say at any end step you win the game.

In my understanding this scenario will always end in a draw, or does it matter on which step **Player A** is playing *“Mirrorweave”*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The last player in turn order with 4 or more creatures on the board will win, so if **Player A** plays [Mirrorweave](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mirrorweave) on their own turn **Player B** will win.

As per **603.2b** when the end step begins all the Biovisionaries will attempt to add their abilities onto the stack, this is done in the standard *APNAP* order.

During **Player A**'s end step as the active player they will add 4+ copies of the *if you control four or more creatures named Biovisionary, you win the game* ability onto the stack, then **Player B** will add 4+ copies of their own onto the stack.

Then as per **405.5** the top ability will resolve first, winning the game for **Player B**

Comment: Note that Mirrorweave is an instant, so if Player A is smart, they'll play it during B's turn and win.

Comment: And of course, in a multiplayer game, APNAP order means that the right-most player with 4 "Biovisionaries" would have the trigger resolve first and win the game.